# DisplayAttribute not respected when view model is lcoated in other assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I moved only model class to other assembly, all other stuff is pretty basic (I just moved to areas account registration)

```
  public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }


@model NewAssembly.Models.AccountViewModels.RegisterViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>

<form  asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

After it I don't see display name near input controls,
what should I do for fix it at ASP.NET Core ?

Comment: Slight correction, not an answer, but you moved your ViewModels to another assembly. And you arranged them below the Models, which is definitely strange.

Comment: Make sure (check and add to your post) that the main project also references the Annotations assembly.

Comment: OK, just did a little check. It works fine on my PC.

Comment: Please don't use ASP.NET Core and .NET Core interchangeably!!! ASP.NET Core is an Rest Api/MVC webstack, .NET Core is a runtime. Your question is in anyway related to the runtime

Comment: @HenkHolterman I believe I got some issue with TagHelper , not generate right HTML output, by some reason